# express js 4 how to serve json results without rendering any views /css

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using express 4 in order to create a json API service.
I can't seem to define it to send a simple json without trying to render the view.

```
var express     = require('express');
var router      = express.Router();

module.exports = function (app, namespace) {
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.json({'body': 123});
    });


    app.use(namespace + '/v1', router);
};
```

when I access the route it's

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Volumes/api_service/init/views"
```

I tried to remove the views engine all together

```
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

but it yells with this error

```
No default engine was specified and no extension was provided
```

Comment: Did you try like adding an error view and see what the error is or something like that?

Comment: I wrote that the error. It's `Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Volumes/api_service/init/views"`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're making any calls to `res.render` such as in an error handler that are generated by the 'express generate', then you'll see the error you described.  For a json API service you probably don't need to render anything so just don't call `render()`, instead call `res.send()` with the status res.status set to 404 or 500.

So basically, replace this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
```

with this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
   return;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

eventually it was the express generic catch 404's that made all the routes unvailables.

> ```
> app.use(function(req, res, next) {
>     var err = new Error('Not Found');
>     err.status = 404;
>     next(err);
> });
> ```

removing him solved it.