# How to properly call an external api to use from within express application to build my own restful api?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, rest, express

I'am trying to create a restful api but I need to use an external api quandl to build my api, when i try to use my api from the client(built in angularjs) i get a 500 internal server error and No default engine was specified and no extension was provided in command line. i know my api work cause i tested it with postman, its just not working from the client.
I tried looking at this post : [express js 4 how to serve json results without rendering any views /css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296031/express-js-4-how-to-serve-json-results-without-rendering-any-views-css) but it wasnt helpful.

```
module.exports = function(io){
    var q = require('q');
    var request = require('request');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Stock = mongoose.model('Stock');
    var base_url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/";
    var dotjson = ".json" 
    var apiKey = "?api_key=" + process.env.quandl_apiKey;

    function sendJsonResponse(res,status,content){
        res.status(status);
        res.json(content);
    }

    // get stock data using quandl api  
    function stockData(name){
        var deferred = q.defer();
        var d = new Date();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var date = d.getDate();

        request({
            url: base_url + name + dotjson + apiKey,
            qs:{
                start_date:(year-1) + '-' + month + '-' + date,
                end_date:year + '-' + month + '-' + date
            }
        },function(error,response,body){
            if(error){
                deferred.reject('Error: ' + error);
            }else if(response.statusCode !== 200){
                deferred.reject('Invalid Status Code: ' + response.statusCode);
            }else{
                deferred.resolve(body);
            }

        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    // get stock data that is stored in database
    function getStockInDatabase(req,res){
        Stock.find({},function(err,stock){
            if(err){
                sendJsonResponse(res,404,err);
            } else {
                sendJsonResponse(res,200,stock);
            }
        })
    }

    // create stock data to be stored in database
    function createStockData(req,res){
        var stockDatas;
        stockData(req.body.name.toUpperCase())
               .then(function(stock){
                  stockDatas = JSON.parse(stock);
                  Stock.create({
                    name:stockDatas.dataset.name,
                    symbol:stockDatas.dataset.dataset_code
                  },function(err,stk){
                    if(err){
                        sendJsonResponse(res,400,err)
                    }else{
                        sendJsonResponse(res,201,stk);
                        io.emit('stock',stockDatas);
                    }
                  })
               })
              .catch(function(err){
                sendJsonResponse(res,404,err);
              })
    } 

    // delete stock data in database
    function deleteStockData(req,res){
        Stock
            .findByIdAndRemove(req.body._id)
            .exec(function(err,stock){
                    if(err){
                        sendJsonResponse(res,404,err);
                    }else {
                        sendJsonResponse(res,204,null);
                    }
            })
    } 

    return {
        getStockInDatabase:getStockInDatabase,
        createStockData:createStockData,
        deleteStockData:deleteStockData
    }
}
```

angular service to use api:

```
  (function(){
   'use strict'
    angular
     .module('app.common')
     .factory('stockService',stockService);

     stockService.$inject = ['$http'];

     function stockService($http){

        function getStock(){
            return $http.get('/api/stocks');
        } 

        function getStockInDatabase(){
            return $http.get('api/stocks/database');
        }

        function createStock(data){
            return $http.post('/api/stocks',data);
        }

        function deleteStock(data){
            return $http.delete('/api/stocks',data);
        }

        return{
            getStockInDatabase:getStockInDatabase,
            createStock:createStock,
            deleteStock:deleteStock
        }

     }
})()
```

app.js configuration

```
require('dotenv').load();
var express = require('express');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var io = socketio();
require('./api/models/db'); 

var app = express();
app.io = io;
var apiRoute = require('./api/routes/index')(io);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use('/api', apiRoute);

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
 next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error', {
   message: err.message,
   error: err
   });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500).send({
  message: err.message,
  error: {}
 })
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Maybe the external server does not support cross origin ajax call?

Comment: okay so i would need to find a way to get around the cross origin ajax call when i use quandl.

Comment: If you are getting data from a server, that server should support @CrossOrigin call. There is nothing you can do on your client side.

Comment: Typically CORS will reply with an error referencing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. I suspect you may have another issue at play. If it is working in Postman, then the issue is likely your client. Can you post a snippet of your calling function from the Angular client?

Comment: Also, if you have control of an Express service, you can bypass CORS by providing a proxy route in your service. That way, your client calls your Express API, which in turn issues a request to the 3rd party service and returns the response to you.

Comment: Can you update your code with your main app.js file? I have a feeling it's because you've not configured a view engine (even if you don't use one, you might need one).

Comment: Try do the following 1. `npm install jade --save` 2. Put the following in your app.js `app.set('view engine', 'jade');`, this should configure express to set the view engine to jade, and hopefully fixing your error.

Comment: It looks like Express handles the error message (for example, when it can not process route or try converting circular structure to JSON), but can not withdraw, because the template engine is not connected. Try to turn on the engine, and see what are the error messages when accessing the API direct from the browser not from angular.

Answer (score 0):

No default engine specified error comes when you have not specified any content serving engine in express.. for you views or html files.

Try using 
app.set('views', 'html page location');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

You might have to additionally require jade.